# How pass parameter from List mapper method to Object mapper method in Java mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I cannot pass some common parameter from List mapper (String company) to Object mapper

```
@Mapper
public abstract class EmployeeMapper {
public abstract Employee getEmployeeFromDTO(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO, String 
company);
@AfterMapping
public void addCompany(@MappingTarget Employee employee, String company) {
   employee.setCompany(company);
}
public abstract List<Employee> getEmployeeFromDTOs(List<EmployeeDTO> employeeDTOs, 
String company);
}
```

At first I used interface not abstract class. And there were no @AfterMapping method. Indeed I do not know how correctly pass it as @Context String company. Is it possible without @Context and @AfterMapping, or at least with it?
So my question is exactly how pass  "String company" when list mapper getEmployeeFromDTOs would call in sequence "item" mapper getEmployeeFromDTO. If it would be passed to last method I would easily map common "company" to Employee as constant with @Mapping as EmployeeDTO has no such data. The other way around I suppose is to use @Context and @AfterMapping.
In this case should I put @AfterMapping method before or after relative mapping method? Whether I should put @AfterMapping method inside Employee/EmployeeDTO class?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my solutions:

Classes:

```
public class Message {
    private String level;
    private List<MessageData> messages;
}

public class MessageData {
    private String appId;
    private long dateCreated;
    private String type;
}


public class Event {
    private String type;
    private String processId;
    private List<EventData> events;
}

public class EventData {
    private String name;
    private long dateCreated;
}
```

Solution #1: Using Context

```
@Mapper
public interface MessageMapper2 {
    @Mapping(target = "level", constant = "MEDIUM")
    @Mapping(target = "messages", source = "event", qualifiedByName = "mapEventsToMessages")
    Message mapEvenToMessage(Event event, @Context String progressId);

    List<MessageData> mapEventsToMessages(List<EventData> events, @Context String progressId);


    @Mapping(target = "type", source = "name")
    @Mapping(target = "appId", expression = "java(progressId)")
    MessageData mapEventDataToMessageData(EventData eventData, @Context String progressId);

}
```

Solution #2: If the property is inside the source object, this solution will work

messageData.appId = event.processId

```
@Mapper
public interface MessageMapper {

        @Mapping(target = "level", constant = "MEDIUM")
        @Mapping(target = "messages", source = "event", qualifiedByName = "mapEventsToMessages")
        Message mapEvenToMessage(Event event);

        @Named("mapEventsToMessages")
        default List<MessageData> mapEventsToMessages(Event event) {
               return event.getEvents().stream()
                        .map(eventData -> new MessageData(event.getProcessId(), eventData.getDateCreated(), eventData.getName()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
}
```